# Correctly subclassing a context manager in Python

Tags: python, exception, inheritance, with-statement, contextmanager

If I have a class `Foo` that is a context manager, and I have a class `Bar` that is a subclass of it that also has actions it needs to perform on enter/exit, how can I implement `Bar` so that it behaves *exactly* as if it were in a nested with-statement inside the super class?

This would be a naive (incorrect) implementation attempt:

```
class Foo:

    def __enter__(self):
        enter_foo_actions()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return exit_foo_actions(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

class Bar(Foo):

    def __enter__(self):
        super().__enter__()
        enter_bar_actions()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        exit_bar_actions(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
        return super().__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
```

This obviously has many issues (maybe even more):

- If `enter_bar_actions()` raises an exception then `super().__exit__()` is not called
- If `exit_bar_actions()` raises an exception, `super().__exit__()` is not called, instead of still being called but with the details of the new raised exception
- If `exit_bar_actions()` returns `True` to suppress the exception then `super.__exit__()` should actually be called with all `None` inputs, not again with the original exception
- `Bar` returning `self` is hard-coded, it would be better if it returns whatever `Foo` returns

Note that due to application-specific reasons I do indeed need to have `Foo` and `Bar` as classes, not decorated context manager methods. Also, I really do need `Bar` to inherit from `Foo` (be a `Foo` instance) for interoperability with other code. I need a class that is both a `Foo` and a context manager at the same time.

Comment: All context managers are classes. `contextlib.contextmanager` just produces an instance of a class whose `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods make use of the decorated generator function.

Comment: Fair point, but is there a way then of getting `contextlib.contextmanager` to produce an instance of `Foo` that has `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods that make use of the decorated generator function and performs the required task?

Answer (score 1):

The following approach seems to do the trick (up to what is possible, see below):

```
class Bar(Foo):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__stack = contextlib.ExitStack()

    def __enter__(self):
        with self.__stack as stack:
            ret = super().__enter__()
            stack.push(super().__exit__)
            self.enter_bar_actions()
            stack.push(self.exit_bar_actions)
            self.__stack = stack.pop_all()
        assert self.__stack is not stack
        return ret

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return self.__stack.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
```

Note that, furthermore, if you have a field `manager` of Bar that is also a context manager that you would additionally like to enter and exit along with Bar, then you can just call:

```
manager.__enter__()
stack.push(manager.__exit__)
```

at the location of `self.enter_bar_actions()`.

I say the solution is "up to what is possible", because there is an irreconcilable problem if `self.enter_bar_actions()` raises an error that is then suppressed by `Foo.exit_foo_actions()` (by this method returning `True`). If in this situation `Bar.__enter__` does not raise an exception, then the contents of the `with` statement will be executed despite the failed enter of `Bar`, which is wrong behaviour. But if instead `Bar.__enter__` raises an exception, then `Bar.__exit__` is never called and has no chance to suppress the error, which is also wrong behaviour then. The assert statement in the `Bar.__enter__` implementation raises an AssertionError if this irreconcilable situation occurs, as there's nothing cleaner you can do.

There is only a tiny tiny difference between my solution and nested with statements, in the case that both Foo and Bar raise exceptions in their `__exit__` implementations. In my case, the raised Foo error will not be chained to the previously occurred Bar error, while in the with-statement case it will be. For almost all applications this should be essentially irrelevant. Note that the 'differing' behaviour of my solution is identical to the behaviour of entering both Foo and Bar sequentially in an ExitStack, which is also commonly thought to be totally identical to nested with-statements... (but evidently it is not to 100%)

My solution also supports multi-subclassing by the way. So some `Cat` class can inherit from Bar and also do exactly the same thing.

Here is complete code that demonstrates my solution and all the points I have made:

```
# Imports
import sys
import traceback
import contextlib

def enter_foo_actions():
    print("ENTERING FOO")
    # raise ValueError("Failed to enter Foo")
    return 42  # Test not returning self

def enter_bar_actions():
    print("ENTERING BAR")
    # raise ValueError("Failed to enter Bar")
    return 120

def enter_cat_actions():
    print("ENTERING CAT")
    # raise ValueError("Failed to enter Cat")
    return 411

# noinspection PyUnusedLocal
def exit_foo_actions(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    print(f"EXITING FOO: {exc_type} {exc_val}")
    # raise ValueError("Failed to exit Foo")
    # return True
    return False

# noinspection PyUnusedLocal
def exit_bar_actions(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    print(f"EXITING BAR: {exc_type} {exc_val}")
    # raise ValueError("Failed to exit Bar")
    # return True
    return False

# noinspection PyUnusedLocal
def exit_cat_actions(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    print(f"EXITING CAT: {exc_type} {exc_val}")
    # raise ValueError("Failed to exit Cat")
    # return True
    return False

def with_actions(value):
    print(f"INSIDE WITH STATEMENT {value}")
    # raise ValueError("Failed inside with statement")

class Foo:

    def __enter__(self):
        return enter_foo_actions()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return exit_foo_actions(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

class RawBar:

    def __enter__(self):
        return enter_bar_actions()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return exit_bar_actions(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

class RawCat:

    def __enter__(self):
        return enter_cat_actions()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return exit_cat_actions(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

class Bar(Foo):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__stack = contextlib.ExitStack()

    def __enter__(self):
        with self.__stack as stack:
            ret = super().__enter__()
            stack.push(super().__exit__)
            enter_bar_actions()
            stack.push(exit_bar_actions)
            self.__stack = stack.pop_all()
        assert self.__stack is not stack
        return ret

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return self.__stack.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

class Cat(Bar):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__stack = contextlib.ExitStack()

    def __enter__(self):
        with self.__stack as stack:
            ret = super().__enter__()
            stack.push(super().__exit__)
            enter_cat_actions()
            stack.push(exit_cat_actions)
            self.__stack = stack.pop_all()
        assert self.__stack is not stack
        return ret

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return self.__stack.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

# Main function
# noinspection PyTypeChecker
def main():

    try:
        print("BEFORE WITH STATEMENT")
        with Bar() as value:
            with_actions(value)
        print("AFTER WITH STATEMENT")
    except ValueError:
        traceback.print_exc()

    print("-" * 80)

    try:
        print("BEFORE WITH STATEMENT")
        with Foo() as value, RawBar():
            with_actions(value)
        print("AFTER WITH STATEMENT")
    except ValueError:
        traceback.print_exc()

    print("-" * 80)

    try:
        print("BEFORE WITH STATEMENT")
        with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
            value = stack.enter_context(Foo())
            stack.enter_context(RawBar())
            with_actions(value)
        print("AFTER WITH STATEMENT")
    except ValueError:
        traceback.print_exc()

    print("=" * 80)

    try:
        print("BEFORE WITH STATEMENT")
        with Cat() as value:
            with_actions(value)
        print("AFTER WITH STATEMENT")
    except ValueError:
        traceback.print_exc()

    print("-" * 80)

    try:
        print("BEFORE WITH STATEMENT")
        with Foo() as value, RawBar(), RawCat():
            with_actions(value)
        print("AFTER WITH STATEMENT")
    except ValueError:
        traceback.print_exc()

    print("-" * 80)

    try:
        print("BEFORE WITH STATEMENT")
        with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
            value = stack.enter_context(Foo())
            stack.enter_context(RawBar())
            stack.enter_context(RawCat())
            with_actions(value)
        print("AFTER WITH STATEMENT")
    except ValueError:
        traceback.print_exc()

# Run main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(0 if main() else 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

(More of a comment that doesn't fit in a comment, but you can determine if this provides a useful answer or can be deleted.)

---

If you can avoid inheritance, you should. I can't tell from the question if an [`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) would meet your criteria (aside from subleasing `Foo`, which it definitely does not), but here's what I was thinking.

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with ExitStack as es:
    f = es.enter_context(Foo())  # with Foo() as f:
    b = es.enter_context(Bar())  #    with Bar() as b:
    ...
```

Before leaving the `with` statement, first `b.__exit__` will be called, followed by `f.__exit__`.

Comment: If it were possible to avoid subclassing (which I can't though for my use case), then this would be an option. But in that case directly doing `with Foo() as f, Bar() as b:` would be simpler and work too? Or if the actions of `Bar.__enter__` depends on `f` then simply two nested with statements.